# filtering a javascript table based upon its values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My table/Array is created in Javascript and is not hard codded in HTML.

I am trying to filter and return the table based on any one who has visited the UK.

I want to place a function with the parameters of (candidates, countries).

```
var people = [
      { name: "Matt", countries: ["UK", "USA", "Russia"] },
      { name: "Simon", countries: ["Canada", "China"] },
      { name: "Ben", countries: ["UK", "India"] },
      { name: "Katie", countries: ["UK", "China"] },
      { name: "Omar", countries: ["Canada", "China"] },
      { name: "Simon", countries: ["India", "China", "USA"] },
    ];
```

I have tried

```
people.filter(person=>person.countries.includes('UK'))
```

However the table is not dynamic and does not change to reflect this on my webpage if i use this code, instead it just returns the original array of 'people'. Why doesn't this approach work?

Comment: `people.filter(person=>person.countries.includes('UK'))`

Comment: *"I am trying to filter"* ... show us what you have actually tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is for you to show your attempts to solve issues yourself and others help when code doesn't work as expected

Comment: This works - however when i console.log(people) after this code it still brings back the original array, instead of the new array which should only include those people who have been to the UK

Comment: `filter` returns a new Array, it doesn't modify the original. Try `people = people.filter(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what are you looking for:

```
const people = [
  { name: "Matt", countries: ["UK", "USA", "Russia"] },
  { name: "Simon", countries: ["Canada", "China"] },
  { name: "Ben", countries: ["UK", "India"] },
  { name: "Katie", countries: ["UK", "China"] },
  { name: "Omar", countries: ["Canada", "China"] },
  { name: "Simon", countries: ["India", "China", "USA"] },
];

const filterCandidates = (candidates, country) =>
  candidates.filter(({ countries }) =>  countries.includes(country));
```

result:

> [{"name":"Matt","countries":["UK","USA","Russia"]},{"name":"Ben","countries":["UK","India"]},{"name":"Katie","countries":["UK","China"]}]

https://es6console.com/jtm4kvvn/